# Google Closure Compiler max bytes

Tags: php, google-closure-compiler

I noticed in the `Minify_JS_ClosureCompiler->min()` method this condition:

```
if ($bytes > 200000) {
    throw new Minify_JS_ClosureCompiler_Exception(
        'POST content larger than 200000 bytes'
    );
}
```

My project is well in excess of 200k of JavaScript. Does anybody know why this exception is here?

It's hard-coded as a conditional value and not a variable which I can edit in the config.php so I assume it has some underlying importance, but I can't find a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ:

> *Are there any restrictions on the size of the files that can be compiled?*
>   The compilation web service has a maximum file size, but the standalone compiler application does not.

I guess, but really don't know, that the limit is intended for the web service that Google provides. That is, if you were to set up your own web service, you could get rid of that limitation if you wanted.